# Cant seem to resolve a syntax error in a contact picker

Tags: android, syntax-error, android-contacts

Alright folks, I'm getting a syntax error on a line of code and I can't seem to figure out why. I've only been tinkering with android for a short time, but I'm pretty certain I've followed the given examples rather well, but just cant get rid of this error for the life of me. The code is for the contact picker so I can populate an edittext with a persons number and then send a picture using an mms intent to that number. I've marked the spot where I'm getting the error, and cant quite finish what i was attempting with it until its resolved. (only showing the section with the problem)

```
break;


case R.id.contact:
  Intent k = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(k, 1);


  @Overide
  public void onActivityResult (int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  //<Getting the syntax errors here
  super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

   {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
      Uri contactData = data.getData();
      Cursor cur = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
      ContentResolver contect_resolver = getContentResolver();

      if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String name = "";
        String no = "";

        Cursor phoneCur = contect_resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, 
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID = " = ?", new String [] { id }, null);

        if (phoneCur.moveToFirst()) { name = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        no = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        }
      }
    }
  }
}

break;  

Now the errors it is throwing are:
- Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
- Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
- Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
- Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
- Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
```

All in that line. Im totally clueless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All in what line?

In any case, you're trying to define a method (`onActivityResult`) right in the middle of a switch statement, if the first few lines of context are to be believed. You can't define a method there.

Comment: The switch was for my buttons and thats exactly what I was attempting. Looks like Ill be going back and making them all onclick individually, and reworking it. Still learning, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

See this line..

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID = " = ?"
```

change to...

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?"
```

Try this first... ^^